# Cognos BI Graph Sorting not working

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi

I need to create a graph in cognos bi. My query and everything is ready and working fine. However, when i create the graph it does not sort as i want it to be.

I selected month name and the month number in different columns.
Put the month name in x axis
Sorted x axis with the month number. However, it still gives me the default order.

Thanks

Comment: You didn't indicate what the "default order" was. Was it alphabetical by month name or some other sorting? Can you include a screenshot?

Comment: See the screenshots below, 

seems like sorts by y axis however i did not defined and found any sorting option for y axis. Tried to sort x axis by different options, asc desc but it does not respond..

http://www.hizliresimyukle.com/images/2017/10/05/ScreenShot2017-10-05at08.29.02.png

http://www.hizliresimyukle.com/images/2017/10/05/ScreenShot2017-10-05at08.29.19.png

Comment: I was hoping to see the output you are currently getting as well as the graph definition. You can edit your question and add the images directly to it.

Comment: Cognos has many tools and many versions. Looking at your screenshot I guess its Cognos 10 report studio? Please provide this info in future. It looks like you've nested ORD_MONTHNUM then ordered that. Instead you should just order ORD_MONTHNAME directly.

Comment: Yes it is cognos 10. I found out that i did evertything correct. The problem is i use pareto chart and cognos does not sort pareto chart by x axis. At least, i could not be able to sort it by x axis. I am using pareto chart to see cumulative line. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to replicate your issue using my data but I was able to sort the months correctly.

In my time dimension I have month of year and month name. The first one is a string like '01', '02', '03', ... and other one is obviously month name.

I dragged a bar chart to the page and then dragged month name to `Categories (x-axis)` then I unlocked the cells and clicked month name inside `Categories (x-axis)`. Then I went to the properties list and selected `Sorting` and dragged month of year field to the sort list. My chart sorted correctly. 
[image]

You probably followed the same steps. I listed what I did just in case you missed something simple